# Path variable seem to be ignored

Tags: windows-8, path, environment-variables

Don't know why but some paths listed in the path variable seem to be ignored.
For instance, processing, that when is executed from the right folder it runs without problem, but it is ignored whenever it is called from elsewhere.
I'm trying to make a build for processing in other IDE but the build always falls in calling the processing-java.exe.

I'd upload  a screenshot but don't have reputation enough to do that ;)

So my Path Variable is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\bin;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; 
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Extensis\Suitcase Fusion 4\; 
C:\Program Files\processing-2.2.1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which folder is `processing-java.exe` in, and does it run if you just type it in?  Does the above path get displayed when you do `echo %PATH%` from the command line?

Comment: 'processing-java.exe' is located at 'C:\Program Files\processing-2.2.1'.   When I type 'echo %PATH%', i do get the path variable as listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When its being set in the normal way rather than this list is there a space inbetween like:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\lib; C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\bin; %SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%;

If so remove the Spaces and have like so:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Anoto\gs\gs8.71\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;

Also on the last on finish with C:\Program Files\processing-2.2.1\;

Comment: Also where are you trying to run this from Command Prompt or Run?

Comment: That worked!! I was trying to make work  a build for Processing in SublimeText, but the error gave me the hint that the path variable wasn't working